# Entity Framework 6 - Enable migrations throws a lot of errors

Tags: c#, database, wpf, entity-framework-6

When I try "enable-migrations" in my WPF-application, I get the following errors.
I bet its really easy, but I googled since two days and have no idea whats wrong.

```
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Jukebox.Database.Drawing: : EntityType 'Drawing' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.BitmapEffect: : EntityType 'BitmapEffect' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.BitmapEffectInput: : EntityType 'BitmapEffectInput' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Transform: : EntityType 'Transform' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Geometry: : EntityType 'Geometry' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.PathFigure: : EntityType 'PathFigure' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.PathSegment: : EntityType 'PathSegment' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Brush: : EntityType 'Brush' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Camera: : EntityType 'Camera' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Transform3D: : EntityType 'Transform3D' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Visual3D: : EntityType 'Visual3D' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Model3D: : EntityType 'Model3D' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Material: : EntityType 'Material' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.GradientStop: : EntityType 'GradientStop' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Pen: : EntityType 'Pen' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.GlyphRun: : EntityType 'GlyphRun' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.GlyphTypeface: : EntityType 'GlyphTypeface' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.MediaPlayer: : EntityType 'MediaPlayer' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CacheModes: : The referenced EntitySet 'CacheModes' for End 'BitmapCacheBrush_BitmapCache_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_BitmapEffect_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_BitmapEffectInput_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_Clip_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_OpacityMask_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_Transform_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_BitmapEffect_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_BitmapEffectInput_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_Camera_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_Children_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_Clip_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_OpacityMask_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_Transform_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_BitmapEffect_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_BitmapEffectInput_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_Clip_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_OpacityMask_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_RenderTransform_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'DrawingImage_Drawing_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Drawings: EntityType: EntitySet 'Drawings' is based on type 'Drawing' that has no keys defined.
BitmapEffects: EntityType: EntitySet 'BitmapEffects' is based on type 'BitmapEffect' that has no keys defined.
BitmapEffectInputs: EntityType: EntitySet 'BitmapEffectInputs' is based on type 'BitmapEffectInput' that has no keys defined.
Transforms: EntityType: EntitySet 'Transforms' is based on type 'Transform' that has no keys defined.
Geometries: EntityType: EntitySet 'Geometries' is based on type 'Geometry' that has no keys defined.
PathFigures: EntityType: EntitySet 'PathFigures' is based on type 'PathFigure' that has no keys defined.
PathSegments: EntityType: EntitySet 'PathSegments' is based on type 'PathSegment' that has no keys defined.
Brushes: EntityType: EntitySet 'Brushes' is based on type 'Brush' that has no keys defined.
Cameras: EntityType: EntitySet 'Cameras' is based on type 'Camera' that has no keys defined.
Transform3D: EntityType: EntitySet 'Transform3D' is based on type 'Transform3D' that has no keys defined.
Visual3D: EntityType: EntitySet 'Visual3D' is based on type 'Visual3D' that has no keys defined.
Model3D: EntityType: EntitySet 'Model3D' is based on type 'Model3D' that has no keys defined.
Materials: EntityType: EntitySet 'Materials' is based on type 'Material' that has no keys defined.
GradientStops: EntityType: EntitySet 'GradientStops' is based on type 'GradientStop' that has no keys defined.
Pens: EntityType: EntitySet 'Pens' is based on type 'Pen' that has no keys defined.
GlyphRuns: EntityType: EntitySet 'GlyphRuns' is based on type 'GlyphRun' that has no keys defined.
GlyphTypefaces: EntityType: EntitySet 'GlyphTypefaces' is based on type 'GlyphTypeface' that has no keys defined.
MediaPlayers: EntityType: EntitySet 'MediaPlayers' is based on type 'MediaPlayer' that has no keys defined.
ImageSources: EntityType: EntitySet 'ImageSources' is based on type 'ImageSource' that has no keys defined.
CacheModes: EntityType: EntitySet 'CacheModes' is based on type 'CacheMode' that has no keys defined.
Visuals: EntityType: EntitySet 'Visuals' is based on type 'Visual' that has no keys defined.

   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()
   bei System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   bei System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.CreateMigrationScaffolder(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInitialCreateInternal(DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String contextTypeName, String contextAssemblyName, String migrationsNamespace, Boolean auto, String migrationsDir)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInitialCreate.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Jukebox.Database.Drawing: : EntityType 'Drawing' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.BitmapEffect: : EntityType 'BitmapEffect' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.BitmapEffectInput: : EntityType 'BitmapEffectInput' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Transform: : EntityType 'Transform' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Geometry: : EntityType 'Geometry' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.PathFigure: : EntityType 'PathFigure' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.PathSegment: : EntityType 'PathSegment' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Brush: : EntityType 'Brush' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Camera: : EntityType 'Camera' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Transform3D: : EntityType 'Transform3D' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Visual3D: : EntityType 'Visual3D' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Model3D: : EntityType 'Model3D' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Material: : EntityType 'Material' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.GradientStop: : EntityType 'GradientStop' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.Pen: : EntityType 'Pen' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.GlyphRun: : EntityType 'GlyphRun' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.GlyphTypeface: : EntityType 'GlyphTypeface' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Jukebox.Database.MediaPlayer: : EntityType 'MediaPlayer' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'ColorConvertedBitmap_Source_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'ColorConvertedBitmap_Source_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'CroppedBitmap_Source_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'CroppedBitmap_Source_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'FormatConvertedBitmap_Source_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'FormatConvertedBitmap_Source_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'TransformedBitmap_Source_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'TransformedBitmap_Source_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'TransformedBitmap_Transform_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'BitmapEffectInput_Input_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
CacheModes: : The referenced EntitySet 'CacheModes' for End 'BitmapCacheBrush_BitmapCache_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_BitmapEffect_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_BitmapEffectInput_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_Clip_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_OpacityMask_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'ContainerVisual_Transform_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_BitmapEffect_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_BitmapEffectInput_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_Camera_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_Children_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_Clip_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_OpacityMask_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'Viewport3DVisual_Transform_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_BitmapEffect_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_BitmapEffectInput_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_Clip_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_OpacityMask_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Visuals: : The referenced EntitySet 'Visuals' for End 'UIElement_RenderTransform_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ImageSources: : The referenced EntitySet 'ImageSources' for End 'DrawingImage_Drawing_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Drawings: EntityType: EntitySet 'Drawings' is based on type 'Drawing' that has no keys defined.
BitmapEffects: EntityType: EntitySet 'BitmapEffects' is based on type 'BitmapEffect' that has no keys defined.
BitmapEffectInputs: EntityType: EntitySet 'BitmapEffectInputs' is based on type 'BitmapEffectInput' that has no keys defined.
Transforms: EntityType: EntitySet 'Transforms' is based on type 'Transform' that has no keys defined.
Geometries: EntityType: EntitySet 'Geometries' is based on type 'Geometry' that has no keys defined.
PathFigures: EntityType: EntitySet 'PathFigures' is based on type 'PathFigure' that has no keys defined.
PathSegments: EntityType: EntitySet 'PathSegments' is based on type 'PathSegment' that has no keys defined.
Brushes: EntityType: EntitySet 'Brushes' is based on type 'Brush' that has no keys defined.
Cameras: EntityType: EntitySet 'Cameras' is based on type 'Camera' that has no keys defined.
Transform3D: EntityType: EntitySet 'Transform3D' is based on type 'Transform3D' that has no keys defined.
Visual3D: EntityType: EntitySet 'Visual3D' is based on type 'Visual3D' that has no keys defined.
Model3D: EntityType: EntitySet 'Model3D' is based on type 'Model3D' that has no keys defined.
Materials: EntityType: EntitySet 'Materials' is based on type 'Material' that has no keys defined.
GradientStops: EntityType: EntitySet 'GradientStops' is based on type 'GradientStop' that has no keys defined.
Pens: EntityType: EntitySet 'Pens' is based on type 'Pen' that has no keys defined.
GlyphRuns: EntityType: EntitySet 'GlyphRuns' is based on type 'GlyphRun' that has no keys defined.
GlyphTypefaces: EntityType: EntitySet 'GlyphTypefaces' is based on type 'GlyphTypeface' that has no keys defined.
MediaPlayers: EntityType: EntitySet 'MediaPlayers' is based on type 'MediaPlayer' that has no keys defined.
ImageSources: EntityType: EntitySet 'ImageSources' is based on type 'ImageSource' that has no keys defined.
CacheModes: EntityType: EntitySet 'CacheModes' is based on type 'CacheMode' that has no keys defined.
Visuals: EntityType: EntitySet 'Visuals' is based on type 'Visual' that has no keys defined.
```

DBContext:
I guess I'm missing some code here, but no matter where I look in tutorials, or just the microsoft documentation, I cant figure it out.

```
public class DB : DbContext
    {
        public DB() : base()
        {
            
        }

        public DbSet<Jukebox.Model.Song> Songs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Jukebox.Model.Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Jukebox.Model.Interpret> Interprets {get;set;}
    }
```

Models:

```
public class Album
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ImageSource Coverart { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
        public List<Song> Tracklist { get; set; }

        public Album()
        {
            Tracklist = new List<Song>();
        }

        public string TracklistToString()
        {
            string result = "";

            foreach (Song song in Tracklist)
            {
                result += $"{song.ID};";
            }

            return result.TrimEnd(';');
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }

public class Song
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public Interpret Interpret { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Album Album { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
        public ImageSource CoverArt { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Interpret} - {Title}";
        }
    }

public class Interpret
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Interpret(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public Interpret()
        {

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's `ImageSource` ? It doesn't seem like it's a type supported by EF.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, it set the ImageSource-propertys to [NotMapped], now its working.